# symfony : how to execute an action via a _partial

Tags: php, symfony1, partial, action

in my application, I have a menu which is a partial (_menu.php)

I need in my menu which is on the entire application, to have access to that :

```
$this->user = $this->getUser()->getGuardUser();
$this->unread = Doctrine::getTable('sfSocialMessageRcpt')->countUnreadMessages($this->user);
```

**But how to create an action for my partial which is rendered in the entire application ?**

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, i used components instead.
it fixed my problem